# Creating and verifying that 2 attirbutes are unique in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I need to create a way to have a email and username be unique acreoss all partions of a table (or tables if needed).  I can't seem to find the way other then making only 1 unique (the primary key) and then the other being unique in the partion only.

I want to have an email address check so that each user has both a UNIQUE email AND a UNIQUE username.

So the database CANNOT have:

```
email    username
a@a.com  aa
b@b.com  aa
```

OR:

```
email    username
a@a.com  a
a@a.com  b
```

I need both to be independently unique across the entire system/database.

How is this done? I am using Lambda and DynamoDB.

And I also NEED to know independently which one is NOT UNIQUE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to ensure that `user_names` are unique AND `email_addresses` are unique and that a `user_name` maps to 1 and only 1 `email_address` and an `email_address` maps to 1 and only `user_name`.

One way to do this would be to use two DynamoDB tables.  The first (table A) would use the `user_name` as the HASH and the record associated with it would contain all information about that user.  The second table (table B) would use `email_address` as the HASH and would contain a single additional attribute, the `user_name`.

When creating a new user, you could do a conditional put on table A with a condition of `attribute_not_exists(user_name)`  If this fails, the `user_name` already exists and so the new record would not be created.  If it succeeds, the `user_name` was unique. You could then do a conditional put to table B with a condition of `attribute_not_exists(email_address)`.  If this fails, the `email_address` is already in use and you would either have to delete the record from table A or otherwise resolve the email address conflict with the user.  If the conditional PUT succeeds then you know that the `email_address` is unique and you have successfully created a new, unique user record.

This is a bit more complicated but it does allow you to rely on DynamoDB to guarantee uniqueness and consistency rather than try to achieve that at the application level.

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing. I had the 2 tables part but am figuring out the consistency issues with your 3rd paragraph today. Also what about using a GSI to scan/query? does that work on all partions, like if email was the hash and username was in Email table was the GSI.

Answer (score 1):

dynamodb uniqueness is on hash_key (or composite key: hash+range) only.

i think that the best option in this case is to ensure uniqueness on application level (add GSI on username and try to query for the new username). on email it will be easy to check uniqueness since it table hash key..

Comment: Yeah I am new so I have to figure out how GSI and hash key and range work and are